# How are OpenGL and DirectX are ported to an OS?

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, gpu

OpenGL and DirectX are the ways to communicate with the GPU. But how are they implemented? If a new operating system is developed how is the OpenGL ported to the new OS? How are OpenGL commands are sent to the GPU?

Answer (score 4):

Each GPU comes with a driver that implements directX and/or OpenGL. These are allowed to communicate with the device directly and will translate and send the commands over.

Comment: OpenGL and DirectX both rely on a 'driver' that is typically implemented by the company selling the video hardware. In the case of OpenGL on Windows, it's called a "Installable Client Driver" (ICD). For DirectX, its implemented as part of the "Windows Display Driver Model" ([WDDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Display_Driver_Model)).